# Help! My animals have gone missing

Tags: pattern, steganography, geography, animals

I need your help. I am the proud owner of 17 animals. Unfortunately they have all gone missing in the past few weeks and I have a feeling they could be hiding in the States somewhere. Can you help me retrieve them?

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1a | South Carolina, California, Oregon, Rhode Island, Pennsylvania, Idaho, Ohio, New York |
> | 1b | Arizona, North Carolina, Alaska, Colorado, Oklahoma, Nevada, Delaware, Alabama |
> | 2a | Utah, Maine, Rhode Island, Wyoming, Delaware, Utah, Ohio, Wyoming |
> | 2b | Massachusetts, Michigan, Minnesota, New York, Tennessee |
> | 3a | Louisiana, New Mexico, Idaho, Massachusetts, Wisconsin, Florida, Mississippi, Minnesota |
> | 3b | Vermont, South Carolina, Georgia, Wyoming, Wisconsin, Montana |
> | 4a | Kentucky, California, Tennessee, Virginia, Montana, New Jersey, Minnesota, Colorado |
> | 4b | Pennsylvania, Delaware, Alabama, Wisconsin, Missouri, Connecticut, Kentucky |
> | 5a | Colorado, North Dakota, Oregon |
> | 5b | Oregon, California |
> | 6a | South Dakota, Maryland, North Carolina, Virginia, Washington, New Jersey |
> | 6b | New York, Virginia, Vermont, Texas, Iowa, Indiana, Michigan, Nebraska, Oklahoma |
> | 7a | Idaho, Pennsylvania, Connecticut |
> | 7b | Maine, Texas, Pennsylvania |
> | 8a | Arizona, California, New Mexico, Oregon, Washington; Arkansas, Iowa, Louisiana, Minnesota, Missouri; Alabama, Arkansas, Georgia, Illinois, Indiana, Mississippi, Missouri, North Carolina, Ohio, South Carolina, Virginia, West Virginia; California, Idaho, Kansas, Nebraska, New Mexico, North Dakota, Oklahoma, Oregon, South Dakota, Texas, Utah, Washington |
> | 8b | Illinois, Kansas, Louisiana, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Nebraska, North Dakota, Oklahoma, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Wisconsin; Colorado, Montana, Nebraska, New Mexico, North Dakota, Texas, Wyoming; Arizona, Colorado, Idaho, Kansas, Montana, Nebraska, North Dakota, Oklahoma, South Dakota, Texas, Utah; Alabama, Florida, Georgia, Illinois, Kansas, Kentucky, Minnesota, Missouri, Nebraska, North Dakota, Oklahoma, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Wisconsin |

[image: Grid]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The Animals

What a menagerie! I hope you find them all soon! Do you need help putting up posters? Your 17 animals are:

> SCORPION
>  ANACONDA
>  HEDGEHOG
>  SNAKE
>  SEA HORSE
>  MARMOT
>  KANGAROO
>  PEACOCK
>  CONDOR
>  ORCA
>  PARROT
>  ARMADILLO
>  EEL
>  ELK
>  LION
>  BEAR
>  ELEPHANT

---

### The Clues

The answers for 1a and 1b can be found by:

> Taking the initial letter from each state
>  SCORPION
>  ANACONDA

The answers for 2a and 2b can be found by:
(From Silenius)

> Taking the last letter from each state
>  HEDGEHOG
>  SNAKE

The answers for 3a and 3b can be found by:
(From Silenius)

> Taking the middle letter from each state
>  SEA HORSE
>  MARMOT

The answers for 4a and 4b can be found by:
(From Techidiot)

> Taking the first, then second, then third, etc. letter from each state
>  KANGAROO
>  PEACOCK

The answers for 5a and 5b can be found by:

> Concatenating the two letter abbreviations for each state:
>  CONDOR
>  ORCA (You must have a lot of space to keep an orca!)

The answers for 6a and 6b can be found by: (from Brien)

> Taking the initial letter of each state capital:
>  PARROT
>  ARMADILLO

The answers for 7a and 7b are found by: (From wing-it)

> Counting the letters in each state name and assigning a letter to that number. 1=A, 2=B, etc.
>  EEL
>  ELK

Some observations about 8a and 8b

> There are three semicolons, separating the clues into 4 sections
>  Within each section, the states are alphabetized.

The answers for 8a and 8b can be found by: (From Silenius)

> Separating the clue into components, breaking at the semicolons. For each component, shade those states in on a map. The shaded states will approximate a letter.
>  LION
>  BEAR
>  Example: Arizona, California, New Mexico, Oregon, Washington;
>  [image]

---

### The Grid

> Considering the letters that fall into the grey box, pick the first alphabetically for MIN and vice-versa for MAX. (Well done wing-it!)
>  This does leave MARMOT in a bit of a strange position however!

> [image]
>  The highlighted letters spell out the last animal: ELEPHANT

Comment: 2a/2b last letters: HEDGEHOG/SNAKE

Comment: @Silenus, feel free to append to this answer (or add your own) :)

Comment: 3a/3b middle letters: SEA HORSE/MARMOT

Comment: 1a and 1b are both 8 letters, so "max" might be referring to another property, for example, animal length?

Comment: 4a/4b - KANGAROO/PEACOCK(1,2,3,4,..letters)

Comment: The crossword might be hiding anagram for *CHINKARA* :)

Comment: The crossword appears to be hiding _ELEPHANT_, however this uses _MARMOT_ in the bottom leaving the last two spaces blank, and I have no idea what the min/max clues mean. That would mean either 7a or 7b would be a 3-letter animal staring with _E_, possibly _ELK_, _EMU_, or _EWE_, but don't know what the clue means. Possible (unlikely) solution for 7b: _E_ ast - _W_ est - _E_ ast, but don't know where that would leave 7a.

Comment: You're getting real close! The min-max function isn't applied correctly, though, and the answer to 7a/b isn't right either.

Comment: Yeah, 7 was extremely hopeful!

Comment: 7a/b:  Number of letters in state name correspond to a letter: ELK/EEL. Now all that's left is the min/max function.

Comment: Aha! Thanks wing-it. I was currently looking at state flowers for some clue!

Comment: MIN/MAX may mean to use either the 'larger' or 'smaller' letter (alphabetically). This would match _ELEPHANT_ whenever there are two options for the gray space.

Comment: I did think this with "CHINKARA", and discounted it, but I forgot to check this with the new final answer. I've just had a quick look, All but the last (3) fits nicely.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work for 5 either. O is "greater than" C

Comment: It works for all of them if you only consider the letter that falls in the gray box.

Comment: Oh I see! What are your thoughts on the answer not fitting in the final row?

Comment: My best guess is that it was just done that way to confuse/mislead.

Comment: The way I arrived at the elephant conclusion independently was by lining each word up starting from the first letter and taking the MIN or MAX letter from each index.  So for the last row, clues 3a/3b, you put in "SERMOTSE", and so on

Comment: Well done, you've got it now! The idea with min/max was indeed, as Brien suggests in the comment above, to take the min/max letter per index. Your method works as well, though ;)

Answer (score 5):

Regarding 2a/2b:

> Taking the last letter from each state to get HEDGEHOG and SNAKE.

Regarding 3a/3b:

> Take the middle letter from each state to get SEA HORSE and MARMOT.

Regarding 8a/8b:

> Each clue consists of 4 lists of states. The states in each list are path-connected.

For example, regarding 8a:

> {Arizona, California, New Mexico, Oregon, Washington} form an L-shaped region.
>
>  {Arkansas, Iowa,Louisiana, Minnesota, Missouri} form a vertical line.
>
> {Alabama, Arkansas, Georgia, Illinois,Indiana, Mississippi, Missouri, North Carolina, Ohio, South Carolina,Virginia, West Virginia} form a circle.
>
> {California, Idaho, Kansas, Nebraska,New Mexico, North Dakota, Oklahoma, Oregon, South Dakota, Texas,Utah, Washington} form an N-shaped region.
>
>  Together these spell LION.

For 8b:

> {lllinois, Kansas, Louisiana, Minnesota, Mississippi, Missouri, Nebraska, North Dakota, Oklahoma, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Wisconsin} form a B-shaped region.
>
>  {Colorado, Montana, Nebraska, New Mexico, North Dakota, Texas, Wyoming} form an E-shaped region.
>
>  {Arizona, Colorado, Idaho, Kansas, Montana, Nebraska, North Dakota, Oklahoma, South Dakota, Texas, Utah} form an A-shaped region.
>
>  {Alabama, Florida, Georgia, Illinois, Kansas, Kentucky, Minnesota, Missouri, Nebraska, North Dakota, Oklahoma, South Dakota, Tennessee, Texas, Wisconsin} form an R-shaped region.
>
>  Together these spell BEAR.

Comment: From the first two letters for 8b, I reckon the next two letters will be A and R

Answer (score 2):

Regarding 6a/6b

> Take the first letter from each state's capital to get PARROT, ARMADILLO